# T-SQL: Parsing names to ignore spaces and middle initials

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, parsing

I have a poorly maintained database that includes employee information.  Human Resources requested a report that lists instances where the employee name associated with an insurance coverage does not match the name on the insurance policy.

There are inconsistencies in the formatting of the names in both tables.  It's always last name then first name, but you might see any of the following in either table for a fictional employee named Steven J. Smith:

1. Smith, Steven
2. Smith,Steven
3. Smith, Steven J.
4. Smith,Steven J.

I need to run a query looking for instances where EMPLOYEE.EMP_NAME <> INSURANCE.SUBSCRIBER_NAME while allowing for differences in name formatting as shown above (i.e. picking up that "Smith,Steven J." and "Smith, Steven" are (probably) the same person and igonring them).

```
SELECT 
  EMPLOYEE.EMP_NO
, EMPLOYEE.EMP_NAME
, INSURANCE.SUBSCRIBER_NAME
, INSURANCE.PAYOR_NAME

FROM EMPLOYEE
     INNER JOIN INSURANCE ON EMPLOYEE.EMP_NO = INSURANCE.EMP_NO

WHERE EMPLOYEE.EMP_NAME <> INSURANCE.SUBSCRIBER_NAME
```

I know I want to do a substring to ignore the middle initial, but how do I account for ignoring whether or not there is a space after the comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, your answers helped a lot.  I ended up cutting the name into [lastname][firstname] with no spaces and cutting off the middle initial if it was there.  Here's what eventually worked in eliminating the vast majority of the same-name matches:

```
((CASE
WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',REPLACE(REPLACE(EMPLOYEE.EMP_NAME,', ',''),',','')) = 0
THEN UPPER(REPLACE(REPLACE(EMPLOYEE.EMP_NAME,', ',''),',',''))
ELSE UPPER(LEFT(REPLACE(REPLACE(EMPLOYEE.EMP_NAME,', ',''),',',''),CHARINDEX(' ',REPLACE(REPLACE(EMPLOYEE.EMP_NAME,', ',''),',',''))))
END) <> 
(CASE
WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',REPLACE(REPLACE(INSURANCE.SUBSCRIBER_NAME
,', ',''),',','')) = 0
THEN UPPER(REPLACE(REPLACE(INSURANCE.SUBSCRIBER_NAME
,', ',''),',',''))
ELSE UPPER(LEFT(REPLACE(REPLACE(INSURANCE.SUBSCRIBER_NAME
,', ',''),',',''),CHARINDEX(' ',REPLACE(REPLACE(INSURANCE.SUBSCRIBER_NAME
,', ',''),',',''))))
END))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply `replace` out the comma

```
 WHERE replace (EMPLOYEE.EMP_NAME,',','') <> replace (INSURANCE.SUBSCRIBER_NAME,',','')
```

To find most mismatches...

```
;with cE as 
(select 
     EMP_NO, 
     REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(EMP_NAME,',',''),' ',''),'.','') as namekey 
from EMPLOYEE),
ci as 
(select 
     EMP_NO, 
     REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSCRIBER_NAME,',',''),' ',''),'.','') as namekey 
from INSURANCE)
select *
from ce
    inner join ci on ce.EMP_NO = ci.EMP_NO
where
     not
     (
    (LEN(ce.namekey)< LEN(ci.namekey) and ci.namekey like ce.namekey+'%')
        or
    (LEN(ce.namekey)>= LEN(ci.namekey) and ce.namekey like ci.namekey+'%')
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove all commas and spaces with REPLACE?

```
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(EMPLOYEE.EMP_NAME,' ',''),',','') <> REPLACE(REPLACE(INSURANCE.SUBSCRIBER_NAME,' ',''),',','')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove space after comma and then remove initials

```
declare @Temp table (Name nvarchar(128))

insert into @Temp
select 'Smith, Steven' union all
select 'Smith,Steven' union all
select 'Smith, Steven J.' union all
select 'Smith,Steven J.'

select 
    case
        when N1.Name like '% %' then left(N1.Name, charindex(' ', N1.Name))
        else N1.Name
    end as Name_New,
    T.Name
from @Temp as T
    outer apply (select replace(T.Name, ', ', ',') as Name) as N1
```